# Using Generic Column with LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a base `Entity` type that I use as a base class for multiple entity types: `Customer : Entity`, `Product : Entity`, etc. Each of these has an existing id column named after the entity type: `CustomerId`, `ProductId`, etc. Because these all have a different name but the same function, I decided to use an unmapped generic Id column that each of these could define to reference the "real" Id column for that type:

```
public abstract class Entity<T> where T: Entity<T>
{
    [NotMapped]
    public abstract int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Entity<Customer>
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public override int Id { get => CustomerId; set => CustomerId = value; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, when I try to use it:

```
[HttpPut("put")]
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>>> PutEntity(List<T> entities)
{
    foreach (T entity in entities)
        if (!MyEntities.Any(e => e.Id == entity.Id))
            return NotFound(false);
}
```

I get an exception `The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Customer>.Any(d => d.Id == ___Id_0' could not be translated.`

Is there any way I can fix this to allow LINQ to run the query with a generic reference to a column with an unknown name?

Comment: Just be careful with this code - if you have a thousand entities then you'll fire off a thousand SQL calls. Can you make this happen in a single LINQ query?

Comment: How exactly did you map this? You apparently made `Entity` part of EF's model, but why? That doesn't seem necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the column name to use for the overridden `Id` property instead:

```
public class Customer : Entity<Customer>
{
    [Column("CustomerId")]
    public override int Id { get; set; }
```

Another solution is to use configuration classes. You also can create an inheritance hierarchy of these configuration classes so base entity properties are configured in a single place while you can choose to override configuration values as you see fit.  Quick example:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : BaseEntity
{
    // Id not needed
}

public abstract class BaseEntityConfiguration<TEntity> 
    : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity is BaseEntity
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id); // defined in single location                
    }
}

public class CustomerConfiguration : BaseEntityConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder); // configure base class' properties

        builder
            .Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasColumnName("CustomerId"); // override column name
    }
}
```

Comment: Will either of these cause any kind of conflicts with the existing CustomerId property that is already being declared in the derived class? Will it be okay to have the derived Id property and the separate CustomerId property pointing at the same data column (or the Id pointing at the CustomerId property) side-by-side?

Comment: No, you can't have two properties mapped to the same column.  If you're using `CustomerId` property in your code, why bother with the `Id` property?

Comment: Typically it's convenient for all Entity subtypes to share the same Id property in .NET, even if you want CustomerId, ProductId, etc in the database.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft sure, as my code delivers, but that doesn't jive with what was asked - OP wants to have *two* ID properties per class that maps to the same column in the DB and I'm asking for what purpose

Comment: And in the API?

Comment: It's not so much that I want two properties, as that I need something in the base class that will be able to refer to properties that are already defined in the specifications with different names.

Comment: But why have different properties in the subclasses?  Just use Id for all of them.

Comment: Is there a way to do that and leave the different names exposed in the API? That would also be a suitable solution.

Comment: JsonPropertyName will probably do it, won't it?

Comment: Nope, JsonPropertName doesn't work on the other end: a query coming through the API using the column name can't find it.

Answer (score -1):

That sounds like entity framework cannot translate something to sql. Shot in the dark but does this work any better?

```
[HttpPut("put")]
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>>> PutEntity(List<T> entities)
{
    foreach (T entity in entities)
    {
        int entityId = entity.Id;
        if (!MyEntities.Any(e => e.Id == entityId ))
            return NotFound(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: No go, it gives the exact same error. I'm pretty sure it's because of the extra layer between the LINQ and the actual variable.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't compose the Expression where you need it, compose it where you have the pieces.

Since I couldn't find a way to pass the property to the Controller, I added a new property that returns the needed Expression:

```
public abstract Expression<Func<T, bool>> CompareId { get; }
```

overrode it in the derived class:

```
public override Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> CompareId => (e => e.CustomerId == CustomerId);
```

and substituted it for the whole expression:

```
T entity;
if (!MyEntities.Any(entity.IsId))
    return NotFound(false);
```

It worked!

Maybe not as clean a solution as I would have liked to come up with, but it allows me to get the expression made, and is still a lot less work than creating identical Controllers for every single entity type.

Probably the biggest caveat here is that I was only able to do this because I was basing the Any on a provided entity. If I had just been provided the Id, I wouldn't have had an existing entity to use to call the property. I guess if I run into a case like that, I'll have to figure that out from there.